# 'Missing' library at design-time in VS2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-time

I located a really nice open-source docking solution called 'AvalonDock' on codeplex, and downloaded v1.1, and included the dll in a WPF project in VS2010 Beta 2 (targeting .NET 4.0) - so far so good.

Then I saw that V1.2 was available and it fixed exactly the issue I was having (V1.2 exposes a DP called DocumentsSource on the DockingManager, so I can keep it cleaner MVVM-wise)

So I downloaded the binaries for V1.2.2691, removed the old reference, included the new one and now I cannot for the life of me "see" the library at design-time...

In my Window's XAML, I type in 'xmlns:dock=' and wait for intellisense to present me with a list of namespaces/assemblies... they all appear, but AvalonDock is conspicuous by its absence! If I manually type in the reference (cos I know it's there!) and carry on blindly, the xaml designer complains about missing references and such, but the App builds and runs as expected...

What am I missing? Thanks for your suggestions,
IanR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical... I hunt and hunt and 2 minutes after asking, I find the answer...

Check out [this post](http://cantgrokwontgrok.blogspot.com/2009/10/visual-studio-unknown-build-error.html) - Just 'unblocked' the dll and it all came good :)

Comment: I just loved this quote: `“The file _might_ be blocked?” – If Windows doesn’t know, who does?!`