# Unhandled Exception in XAML - How to solve?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, graphics

Please help me to understand the problem and solve this:
 [this http://img689.yfrog.com/img689/5357/errornj.jpg](http://img689.yfrog.com/img689/5357/errornj.jpg)
Thanks !

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the answers solved the problem...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an assembly is missing, it may be Microsoft.Expression.Interactions or something that assembly itself needs. It could also be the required version or public key token is incorrect.

Comment: How can I check/solve if the required version or the public key token is incorrect ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If it executes OK, but you cannot see the library at design-time, I wonder if it's because the  dll is 'locked'?

I had exactly this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818693/missing-library-at-design-time-in-vs2010)

Comment: I wish this would solve the problem...
I checked the properties of the dll file, but there is no "Security..." section under "Attributes...".
How can I check if the dll is locked ?
Thanks !

Comment: if the section isn't there, then that's probably not the problem - sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a control or trigger that does not exist, from xaml.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the assembly and its footprint from app.config if there is one and try adding the library again. also check from the project props that you are targeting the correct framwork version...